# Spring boot application not working properly in tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have created a small project in spring boot and spring security. It is running perfectly in spring tool suite. And I have created the war file using maven install and deployed to tomcat 9 and trying to run the project. It's opening the login page with out applying the CSS. I have entered the user name and password and submitted. After submitting it's giving HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error. Please help me what went wrong here.
Here is my pom.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.home.ledger</groupId>
    <artifactId>HomeLedger</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>HomeLedger</name>
    <description>HomeLedger</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version><!-- $NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session-core -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId> <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session-jdbc -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId> <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Here my application main class package org.home.ledger;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HomeLedgerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HomeLedgerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(HomeLedgerApplication.class);
    }


}
```

Comment: And what's the URL that gives 404?

Comment: http://localhost:8181/login

Comment: But you are running your application inside tomcat so there must be a context root. What's the name of your WAR?=

Comment: HomeLedger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   this is the war file name

Comment: So the content root is: /HomeLedger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and the url would be localhost:8181/HomeLedger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/login

Comment: http://localhost:8181/HomeLedger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/login is opening the at the first time and I'm able to see the login page. After entering username and password and submitting the form, I'm getting the 404 error and url displaying as localhost:8181/login

Comment: How did you create login? Are you using Spring Security?

Comment: Yes. I used spring security and changed to custom login page instead of default spring security login page

Comment: How did you configure spring security?

Comment: by adding spring-boot-starter-security dependency and by using the custom configuration extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class

Comment: so please show your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: overriding below methods
@Bean
 public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
  DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
  provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  provider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
  return provider;
 }

Comment: @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  
  http
     .csrf().disable()
     .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login","/register","/welcome").permitAll()
     .anyRequest().authenticated()
     .and()
     .formLogin()
     .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
     .and()
     .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
     .clearAuthentication(true)
     .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
     .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll();
 }

Comment: also overring this 
@Override
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**");
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/image/**");
 }

Comment: That's strange: I just created a small demo app and it works. How does your customer login page looks like?

Comment: <form action="/login" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text"
       id="email" name="username"
       placeholder="Enter email / Mobile Mumber" required="required">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label> <input type="password"  id="pwd" name="password"
       placeholder="Enter password" required="required">
     </div>
     
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>

Comment: That looks ok. Can you provide the source code on GitHub? I dont' see any issues so far

Comment: But it's working well in Spring Tool suite. adding the project in GitHub

Comment: https://github.com/mmohan668/HomeLedger.git
here you go.

Comment: Sir, Are you able get the source from GitHub? please confirm.

Comment: yes i've cloned the repo and will have a look now

Comment: The problem are the fixed pathes like /login or /css in the JSP. This does not work because / is the root of Tomcat. I will see how this is best solved

Comment: This works fine. I am so very grateful for your time. Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the context path in Tomcat is generate based on the WAR file name you must use c:url in your JSP files that URL rewriting is happening:

Read more here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm

That way the path independent from the URL it self.

Comment: This works fine. I am so very grateful for your time. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: I'm happy to help